# Material UI responsive based on element size

Tags: reactjs, widget, material-ui, responsive

I'm using React and MaterialUI to build a system that will display widgets inside another (not React-based) web site. I'd like to make the widgets responsive, but they need to respond to their own container width rather than the window width, as I won't know how much of the page the widget will take up.

Options I've considered:

- Polling the container size on an interval basis
- Polling the container size on window resize events
- Setting up the theme breakpoints based on the container and window sizes at startup

These all seem rather ugly solutions to me. Is there an elegant way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of breakpoints you can listen to changes to the component size. You can use [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) hook [useMeasure](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useMeasure.md) to achieve that (it relies on [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), which is supported by all major browsers), like in the following example:

```js
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import { faAddressBook, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { useMeasure } from 'react-use';

const useMyComponentStyle = (params) => {
    const { color } = params;
    const [ref, { width }] = useMeasure();

    const borderColor = width < 150 ? 'red' : width < 400 ? 'yellow' : 'green';
    const icon = width < 250 ? faCoffee : faAddressBook;

    const style = css`
        color: ${color};
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid ${borderColor};
    `;

    return {
        ref,
        style,
        icon,
        width,
    };
};

export const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const { ref, style, icon, width } = useMyComponentStyle(props);

    return (
        <div ref={ref} css={style}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />
            {props.children} [[{parseInt('' + width)}px]]
        </div>
    );
};

const containerStyle = css`
    padding: 100px 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
`;

export const MyContainer = () => (
    <div css={containerStyle}>
        <MyComponent color='blue'></MyComponent>
    </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<MyContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The example above uses [emotion](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion) for the css styles, but the style could be defined using another library, like [jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/tree/master/packages/react-jss) or [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components), or even plain react inline style.

The component `MyComponent` is included inside the container component `MyContainer` that has left and right `padding` with value `200px`, and you can see as you resize your browser view that the `border` color of `MyComponent` is based **on the size of the component itself** (`red` if the width of the component is less than `150px`, `yellow` if it's less than `400px`, otherwise it's `green`), not based on the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

To make various `@material-ui/core` elements take up only as much space as the container you place them in, I'd use the `Grid` component.

I've used the following:

```
<Grid container spacing={24}>
  <Grid item>
    Your content here
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

If you further want your grid item to be responsive to things like screen size, you may do:

```
const grid = {
    xs: 24,
    sm: 24,
    md: 24,
    lg: 12,
    xl: 12,
};
```

and

```
<Grid item {...grid}>
```

Documentation: https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I mean. The problem is that the breakpoints (where the grid item will change from 24 to 12 columns in your example) refer to the actual window size of the browser, and not to the container size for my widget.

Comment: @MartenJacobs did you find a solution that works for you? I have the same need

Comment: Any progress on this topic? Thanks for info guys.